# Why is there a delay in the launch of spark executors?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

While trying to optimise a Spark job, I am having trouble understanding a delay of 3-4s in the launch of the second and of 6-7s third and fourth executors.

This is what I'm working with:

- Spark 2.2
- Two worker nodes having 8 cpu cores each. (master node separate)
- Executors are configured to use 3 cores each.

Following is the screenshot of the jobs tab in Spark UI.

The job is divided into three stages. As seen, second, third and fourth executors are added only during the second stage.
[image: Job description]

Following is the snap of the Stage 0.
[image: Stage 0 description]

And following the snap of the Stage 1.
[image: Stage 1 description]

As seen in the image above, executor 2 (on the same worker as the first) takes around 3s to launch. Executors 3 and 4 (on the second worker) taken even longer, approximately 6s.

I tried playing around with the `spark.locality.wait` variable : values of 0s, 1s, 1ms. But there does not seem to be any change in the launch times of the executors.

Is there some other reason for this delay? Where else can I look to understand this better?

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested to check Spark's [executor request policy](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#request-policy), and review the settings `spark.dynamicAllocation.schedulerBacklogTimeout` and `spark.dynamicAllocation.sustainedSchedulerBacklogTimeout` for your application.

> A Spark application with dynamic allocation enabled requests
>   additional executors when it has pending tasks waiting to be
>   scheduled. ...
>
> Spark requests executors in rounds. The actual request is triggered
>   when there have been pending tasks for
>   `spark.dynamicAllocation.schedulerBacklogTimeout` seconds, and then
>   triggered again every
>   `spark.dynamicAllocation.sustainedSchedulerBacklogTimeout` seconds
>   thereafter if the queue of pending tasks persists. Additionally, the
>   number of executors requested in each round increases exponentially
>   from the previous round. For instance, an application will add 1
>   executor in the first round, and then 2, 4, 8 and so on executors in
>   the subsequent rounds.

Another potential source for a delay could be `spark.locality.wait`. Since in Stage 1 you have quite a bit of tasks with sub-optimal locality levels (Rack local: 59), and the default for `spark.locality.wait` is 3 seconds, it could actually be the primary reason for the delays that you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I checked that the dynamicAllocation is enabled. The launches also do look like exponential requests. But, as per the defaults the `spark.dynamicAllocation.schedulerBacklogTimeout` should be 1s, doesn't seem to be the case here. I am trying by specifying smaller values to see if anything changes.

Comment: My initial suspect was `spark.locality.wait`. But I tried a lot of different values, and the delay did not change. Then I found out (from elsewhere) that `spark.locality.wait` deals with the launch of the tasks (only), when the executors are already launched. And, as can be seen from the event timeline, its the executors which are launched with a delay, not just the tasks. I am not sure if the two things are adding to each other

Answer (score 0):

It takes time for the yarn to create the executors, Nothing can be done about this overhead. If you want to optimize you can set up a Spark server and then create requests for the server, And this saves the warm up time.

Comment: Going by the consistency of the timing the executors are launched (3s on same worker, and 6s on a new one), I thought its the application which is delaying the requesting. For instance, even if I reduce the cores per executor to 2, such that three executors come up in both workers => 2nd and 3rd are delayed again by 3-4s, and 4th to 6th come up after 6s..